# Come in front or Come from front?

Tags: phrase-usage

Let's say I am in a house with two entrances, one in the back, one in front. I need to ask someone which one they took
Should I say

> I did not see you come in. Did you **come in front/back**?

or

> I did not see you come in. Did you **come from front/back**?

Are they both idiomatic? If yes, Which of these two expression a native speaker is more likely to use?

Comment: To me it is idiomatic (AmE).

Comment: It's generally ***the*** front and ***the*** back: *I didn't see you come in. Did you come in **the** front?*  You can expand this with additional words if you like:  "Did you come in *through* the back/front [door]?"  With *back* you can also use *way*: Did you come in the back way?  (Using *way* with front isn't as common- since the front is not an alternate or sneaky way in it's just called "the front door".

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit different between where you came into the house, and where you came from.

> I did not see you come in. Did you come **in** the *front/back door*?

and

> I did not see you come in. Did you come **in from** the *front porch/backyard*?

Answer (score -2):

You are talking about the **source** which is *unknown* to you.

When you talk about the *source*, it is *generally* with the preposition 'from'.

> I did not notice you. Did you come ***from*** the backdoor?

People come **from** somewhere ***as a source*** which is the case here.

> You come ***from*** America 
>  She came ***from*** the top 
>  He came ***from*** the washroom. And so on...